# How to move camera thats attached to player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to recreate a dolphin dive type of feel, as of right now my character is a cube with no animation so I feel like the best way to do this would be to manually move the camera as if the character had just dolphin dived but every time I try to move the camera the entire player itself moves.

Code:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C) && isSprinting) {
    for (float i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        var forceForward = 8f;
        if (isGrounded == true && moveVertical != 0) {
            _rgb.AddForce(fpsCam.transform.forward * forceForward);
            for (float j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
                _camera.AddForce(Vector3.up * 3f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if you need any more information let me know!

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball is dirty. `_rgb`, `_camera`, hierarchy? ...

Comment: And what does "camera attached"  mean?

Comment: I only wrote that much code to avoid writing out a bunch of code that's not necessary to my question I avoided it, _rgb is the rigidbody for my player, and I also added a rigidbody to the camera, turned gravity off, and made it kinematic hoping I could move the rigid body of the camera and not the player but it didn't work. so _rgb is the rigid body to the player, and _camera is the rigid body for the camera. And when I say camera attached, keep in mind I'm new to unity, so theres probably a different word for it but It just means I've attached the camera to the player object

Answer (score 1):

If you want a shortcut, you can make the camera gameobject a child of the player game object. This way it will move with the player.

Comment: I end up doing this surprisingly often. Possible pitfalls include accidentally deleting the player object between scenes, especially to non-game scenes like a main menu, and forgetting to move the camera by relative rather than absolute coordinates afterwards

Comment: There are situations where this isn't the best solution though so I can see why he would ask this question. For example, if you wanted the camera to lag slightly behind the player. In that case, you would require a more complex solution.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues "move the player..." The Q tries to move the cam in some way **without** moving also the player.